# Javascript: new Function() and eval()

Tags: javascript

I'm confused ... Why is the first line of eval working, but the second isn't? Is there a restriction in nesting evals and Function definition or is there an other syntax error?

```
function a(b,c) {console.warn(b+c);}
function d(b,c) {console.warn(b*c);}

eval('new Function("b", "c", "a(b,c); d(b,c);")')(4,5); // working
eval('new Function("b", "c", "a(b,c); eval(\"d\")(b,c);")')(4,5); // not working
```

PS: I know, that this kind of code is nasty - I'm just curious ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that `\"` becomes `"` when parsed, so your code becomes:

```
new Function("b", "c", "a(b,c); eval("d")(b,c);")
```

As you can see, this is not valid. Solution: double-up your backslashes: `\\"d\\"` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
> console.log('\"d\"')
"d"
```

The escape sequence is interpreted by the outer string. You have to double the backslashes.

Comment: Epic Fail! - Thank you very much!